# String "2" toInt returns 50

Tags: kotlin

Im just working through some simple practice problems in kotlin. In my code below I'm taking a number and attempting to add the number members together.  Ex. 29, return 2 + 9 = 11.  There could be a better way to accomplish this but, I'm taking the numbers, converting to string, and then putting them into a list, ie ["2","9"] when I attempt to convert list[0].toInt() it returns 50.  It appears there is some rounding taking place but I have not found another kotlin method to work with.  Can anyone offer some insights? TIA

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  fun addTwoDigits(n: Int): Int {
    val sliced = n.toString().toList()
    val int1 = sliced[0].toInt()
    println(sliced[0]) //returns "2"
    println(int1) // returns 50
    return sliced[0].toInt() + sliced[1].toInt()
  }

  println(addTwoDigits(29))
}
```

Comment: `50` is the [ASCII character code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the character `'2'`

Comment: out of the scope of the initial question, just wanted to know that: you are aware that if you give a number with more than 2 digits, like `123`, it will only add the first 2, `1+2`, right?. And that it will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception when doing numbers `0-9` and it will also always fail for negative numbers?

Comment: @Alex.T the coding problem was called "addTwoDigits" it wasn't for 3 or 4, I would have changed my approach if that were the case.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Koltin Char.toString(), which you are using in line:

> val int1 = sliced[0].toInt()

converts the character using the ASCII Code table.

You can simply add a toString() call before the toInt() call:

> val int1 = sliced[0].toString().toInt()

Comment: oh, nice.  That worked, I would have figured it was already a string because I converted it before they were added to the list.  Is this just a kotlin/java quirk ?

Comment: You are converting an integer `29` into a string `"29"`, splitting that into a list of 2 characters `'2'`,`'9'`, and then printing/adding the numeric code values of those characters (`50`, `57`), not the integer values that they represent (`2`, `9`).